# How can I run a command at successful ethernet connect in Arch?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, arch-linux, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi running ArchARM, and would like to make a reverse SSH tunnel as soon as it connects to the network via ethernet.

I made an executable (`+x`) shell script in `/usr/bin`, and would like that to be run whenever the default network manager acquires an IP on the eth0 interface.

Alternatively, what is the best way I could do this without an SSH tunnel or opening a port on my router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a reverse SSH with the -R arg (i wrote an article in french about this [here](https://z8po.dyndns.info/2013/04/reverse-ssh-possible-quand-les-ports-sont-fermes/) ) and cron or make a service with.

here the stuff translated

```
user@mynewRaspberry :~$ ssh -R 61337:localhost:22 z8po@z8po.dyndns.info
```

after you can login it from another place, here in example from z8po.dyndns.info

```
z8po@hive :~$ ssh z8po.dyndns.info -p 61337
```

Next let's use a *while loop* in your script to check the ssh is forever relaunch.

```
while true do ssh -R 61337:localhost:22 z8po@z8po.dyndns.info done
```

you can maintain your connection with a keep alive on a ssh client or a server, add to /etc/ssh/sshd_config or ~/.ssh/config the folowing line

```
 ClientAliveInterval 60
```

Don't forget to use rsa key insteed of paswsrod for auto login without prompt, or if you really want to use password, change the ssh command with user:password@ip but it is quite less secure.

### **First method Cron it**

make a script checking if allready launched, in /home/USER/autolauncher.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
if ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep yourscript.sh ; then
        exit 0
else
        while true do ssh -R 61337:localhost:22 z8po@z8po.dyndns.info done
        exit 0
fi
```

and edit you crontab

```
crontab -e
```

add it after the other crons jobs; every 5 min launch the previous script (which will not work if already running)

```
   */5 * * * * /home/USER/autolauncher.sh
```

### **Second method : service at startup**

create or copy the script in init.d add the commands in to it using vi:

```
  sudo nano /etc/init.d/autolauncher.sh
```

make it executable

```
  sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/autolauncher.sh
```

update-rc.d to create and configure start:

```
  sudo update-rc.d autolauncher.sh defaults
```

now you have two methods to make your rasperry trying to connect

Comment: Though I don't understand... why is there a while loop in the cron script?

Comment: because of service at startup, it will launch one time, and if crash, relaunch it etc...